# What errors can be suppressed by a debugger?

Tags: c++, g++

I experienced that there are certain errors that can make a programm crash when it is executed as a regular build but will be suppressed when executed in a debugger. I recently experienced this in a Qt project where 99% of the errors that will cause a crash are Segmentation faults caused by dereferencing a Null Pointer.

On Linux i track those with valgrind. Now i am experiencing that my project builds fine on linux with no crashes, but a build in Qt creator on windows will crash at a certain operation. When using the debugger it won't. I experienced the same with valgrind.

What can cause this behaviour and how can i track down the reason for a crash when debugger and valgrind will suppress it?

The Compiler on Linux is g++ 4.4.7 and on windows it's mingw492_32.

Comment: You could try running an optimized build with debug info through the debugger and get the backtrace post-mortem.

Comment: Any program using 2 or more threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One type of bug that can often be masked by a debugger is a 'race condition'.
Since the debugger will usually change the timings between when threads run/are scheduled, running a program under a debugger may often cause race conditions to never (or sometimes always) be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any explicit suppression of exceptions in Windows debugging. You can set up which exceptions trigger a program break under `Debug Menu->Exceptions`, but I don't think that is what you are asking.

I've seen problems that do not reproduce when a Windows program is run from the debugger, by which I mean Visual Studio 20xx. I believe this is because the IDE sets different Win32 and CRT heap memory management flags. Possibly running in the debugger changes the timing subtly also (you have a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)). That's been true whether I run the Debug build or the Release build.  In these instances, my first step is to start the program 'normally', possibly with a startup delay using `Sleep(15000);` or similar. THEN attach the debugger to the started process while the artificial delay gives you time to do so.

This seems to preserve the operating characteristics of the program in a way that running it from the debugger does not. I've found it possible more than once to reproduce odd crashes.

If it still does not reproduce the crash you are going to have to get more creative: add instrumentation; use [Process Dumper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4060) to force a memory dump on crash, and then debug the dump *post mortem*.

Hopefully the first step I mentioned will work because it's increasingly painful if not.

Comment: Doing post mortem debugging of a Qt release build is usually painful if using the official builds because they don't contain the release PDBs (at least for VS, not sure for MinGW). You can generate those but you will have to recompile Qt. See QTBUG-3934 which aims to add those debug symbols to the release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this difference appears because in debug mode you just don't go behind the memory barriers because its layout is different but not because debugger suppresses problems somehow. If you get crash in any mode and at any platform you should fix the bug. Otherwise you will blow off you leg relaying on random events in your program.

Also one of the reasons having crash in release can be program optimization. It also changes layout of memory and causing more crashes. To track these problems you can try to turn on optimization but keep debug information to be able to trace.

Comment: Disregarding the possibility of compiler bugs, there is no reason to expect different behaviour from unoptimized and optimized programs. In both cases they are required to adhere to the rules of the "symbolic machine" defined by the standard. Thus, unless the compiler is buggy the two scenarios should perform the same (except for speed) - anything else is a bug in *your* code.

Comment: Standard contains a lot of "undefined behaviour" cases. Reffering broken pointers is also undefined behaviour and what exacly happens in this case really depends on optimization, memory and code structure. Neither standard nor compiler can't guarantee program behavior in this case.